# Hide the label part in Kartik DatePicker

Tags: datepicker, yii2

I am trying to remove the header part from Kartik DatePicker in Yii2. I try to use the following code.

```
    echo \kartik\date\DatePicker::widget([
        'model' => $employmentMod,
        'form' => $form,
        'attribute' => "[$index]emp_date_from",
        'options' => [
            'placeholder' => 'Select date ...', 
            'template' => '{widget}{error}',
            'class' => 'detaildatepicker', 
            ],
        'pluginOptions' => [                
            'todayHighlight' => true,
            'autoclose' => true,
            'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        ]
    ]);
```

It is still not working. I passed the $form in as I need the validation error to be displayed. Can someone tell me how to use template here?

Comment: As I remember, I deal with this widget before, but I may need a screen shot to show what exactly you want to hide.

Comment: Its not '->label(false)' at the end like normal form widgets?

Comment: What do you mean as "header part"? Is it prepended elements picker and remove buttons? There no label generated by this widget.

Answer (score 0):

add `type` option for this widget to specify markup of component:

```
echo \kartik\date\DatePicker::widget([
        'model' => $employmentMod,
        'form' => $form,
        'attribute' => "[$index]emp_date_from",
        'options' => [
            'placeholder' => 'Select date ...', 
            'template' => '{widget}{error}',
            'class' => 'detaildatepicker', 
            ],
        'type'=> \kartik\date\DatePicker::TYPE_INPUT,
        'pluginOptions' => [                
            'todayHighlight' => true,
            'autoclose' => true,
            'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        ]
    ]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. This does not work for me. Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes, I've tested it - this code shows only input field without any labels and prepend/append elements

Comment: Show your from  widget begin pls

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using normal form behaviour.

Have a look into this.

```
               $form->field($model, 'start_date')
                    ->label(false)
                    ->widget('kartik\date\DatePicker', [
                        'pluginOptions' => [
                            'format'         => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                            'todayHighlight' => true,
                            'clearButton'    => false,
                        ]
                    ]);
```